# How do I make a curved circular scroll view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-camera, scrollview

As shown in the screenshot obtained from Motorola Camera App, **how do I obtain a circular scroll view or as I'd like to call an Option Wheel**.
On swiping up or down the wheel rottes, showing more options. Similar to a scroll view, but curved.

[image: Option Wheel Motoral Camera App]

Comment: do you want similar to this type of curved view ?

Comment: Yes, I want something as similar or the same as this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use [simple arc layout library](https://github.com/ogaclejapan/ArcLayout)

Add the dependency to your build.gradle.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.ogaclejapan.arclayout:library:1.1.0@aar'
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. This will do. Instead of those circular views, if I include a single scroll view I guess itll do the trick :D Thanks